# Remove duplicate from JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
    "managedObjects": [
         {
            "id": "13289",      
            "name": "xxx"      
         },
         {
            "id": "13290",      
            "name": "yyy" 
         },
         {
            "id": "13289",      
            "name": "xxx" 
         }]
}
```

I'm parsing to JObject

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json)
```

Now, how to remove the duplicate element from this array? I want to remove duplicate element by id from JObject (here `id=13289`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a class for this.

```
// Get your JObject as you've already shown
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

// Use LINQ to create a List<JToken> of unique values based on ID
// In this case the first occurence of the ID will be kept, repeats are removed
var unique = obj["managedObjects"].GroupBy(x => x["id"]).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

// Iterate backwards over the JObject to remove any duplicate keys
for (int i = obj["managedObjects"].Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var token = obj["managedObjects"][i];
    if (!unique.Contains(token))
    {
        token.Remove();
    }
}

// Re-serialize into JSON
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Output:

> {
>     "managedObjects":[
>     {
>       "id":"13289",
>       "name":"xxx"
>     },
>     {
>       "id":"13290",
>       "name":"yyy"
>     }
>     ]
>     }

Additional properties alongside "name" should be kept as well as any other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to directly specifiy that with Json.Net, but a solution would be (if your order of the array does not matter) do read the json in a custom class structure with an overloaded `Equals` method:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);

// ...

public class Container
{
    public HashSet<ManagedObject> ManagedObjects { get; set;}
}

public class ManagedObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(ManagedObject other)
    {
        return string.Equals(Id, other.Id);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((ManagedObject)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Id != null ? Id.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good if without custom class as the JSON contains so many inner objects not only id and name.

Comment: @balaji there is converter for that: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ManagedObject type locally and then deserialize your json to this type. You could then use linq to get the distinct list. Here is a console application demonstrating this;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication28
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json =
                "{\r\n\"managedObjects\": [\r\n{\r\n  \"id\": \"13289\",      \r\n  \"name\": \"xxx\"      \r\n},\r\n{\r\n    \"id\": \"13290\",      \r\n  \"name\": \"yyy\" \r\n},\r\n{\r\n    \"id\": \"13289\",      \r\n  \"name\": \"xxx\" \r\n}]\r\n}";

            var managedObjectCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ManagedObjectCollection>(json);

            var distinctManagedObjects = managedObjectCollection.managedObjects.GroupBy(a => a.id).Select(b => b.First());

            foreach (var distinctManagedObject in distinctManagedObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Name: {1}", distinctManagedObject.id, distinctManagedObject.name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class ManagedObjectCollection
        {
            public IEnumerable<ManagedObject> managedObjects { get; set; }
        }
        class ManagedObject
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate that you have provided a simplified example but for a more complex example you would simply need to create/expand the classes to which you were deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following classes:

```
public class ManagedObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ManagedObject> ManagedObjects { get; set; }
}

class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<ManagedObject>
{
    public bool Equals(ManagedObject x, ManagedObject y)
    {
        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ManagedObject obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize your json like follows:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

and remove the duplicates from its ManagedObjects list:

```
var newManagedObject = test.ManagedObjects.Distinct(new MyComparer()).ToList();
test.ManagedObjects = newManagedObject;
```

A bit messy though.